# SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server

```
 SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 (SQL: select * from sys.sysobjects where id = object_id(migrations) and xtype in ('U', 'V'))
```

Estoy usando `PHP 7.4` y agregado la `*.dll` para `7.4` pero sin embargo me manda un error y me manda al link  de descarga de drivers.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Descargaste los drivers?

Comment: claro, por eso se muestra en phpinfo)=